# TypeError: 'deploy' is not a function

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, geth-debugging

When running the following code within geth console, I am recieving the following error:

```
TypeError: 'deploy' is not a function

var storageContractAbi = storageOutput.contracts['contracts/29.sol:ethForAnswersBounty'].abi
var storageContract = new web3.eth.contract(JSON.parse(storageContractAbi))
var storageBinCode = "0x" + storageOutput.contracts['contracts/29.sol:ethForAnswersBounty'].bin

storageContract.deploy({
    data: storageBinCode,
    arguments: [29]
}).send({
    from: eth.accounts[0],
    gas: 1000000
})
```

If I am reading the manual correctly, I am not sure what I am doing wrong here. https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#deploy

The contract is created fine if I call it this way:

```
var storageInstance = storageContract.new({
  from: eth.accounts[0],
  data: storageBinCode,
  gas: 1000000
})
```

Any help much appreciated as I would really like to use promises after the send().

Comment: Looks this is a typo, `web3.eth.contract` should have contract with capitcal `C`. Like this `web3.eth.Contract`.Try it and let me know if it is resolved.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, this then causes "err: TypeError: 'Contract' is not a function".

Comment: Geth version: 1.8.20

Comment: Have you used the complete `new web3.eth.Contract`? also is your web3 version 1.0.0.beta.** ?

Comment: It appears geth 1.8.20 uses version "0.20.1" of web3. Unfortunately for me (if it's a geth issue) this web3 version appears to be baked into geth. I wasn't sure what you meant by "Have you used complete..."

Comment: It seems you are developing it in node.js. I think you will be using web3 by installing your specific version.

Answer (score 1):

I think this might be a limitation in the current version of geth 1.8.20. I was using geth console and piping in the javascript from my original question.

I've now rewritten my deployment pipeline in nodejs so I can pull in web3@1.0.0-beta.37 and the exact same syntax is now working fine.

Hope this helps someone else out.